# Números aleatorios srand

Tags: c++

Consiste en sacar dos números al azar, pero seguramente hay que reinicializar el srand porque sale mal y en otro proyecto que tengo salen los dos numeros iguales.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int numero,numero2;
  srand(time(NULL));
  numero=rand() % 5+1;

  cout << "El numero es:"<<numero<<endl;

  srand(time(NULL));
  numero=rand() % 5+1;

  cout << "El segundo numero es:"<<numero2;

}
```

Comment: "*Sale mal y en otro proyecto que tengo salen los dos numeros iguales*" ¿Qué significa eso? ¿Qué sale mal? ¿A qué te refieres con los números iguales?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Srand()**, *solo se inicializa una vez en el programa que ejecutes*, para que empiece a correr con la variable o función que le pasaste, en este caso **time(NULL)**.
Luego, para generar varios números, tienes que guardar cada uno en una variable diferente, siendo esto la mejor forma.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;

int main(){
   int numero,numero2;
   srand(time(NULL));
   numero=rand()%5+1;
   numero2=rand()%5+1;
   cout<<"El primer numero es:"<<numero<<endl;
   cout<<"El segundo numero es:"<<numero2<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema en el programa no es con `rand()` sino en las variables utilizadas. En la segunda llamada a `rand()` haces lo siguiente:

`numero=rand() % 5+1;`

Segúramente fué un error de copy-paste. Creo que tu intención es hacer lo siguiente:

`numero2=rand() % 5+1;`

Trata de usar nombres de variables mas descriptivos de modo que evites esta situación y el programa sea mas legible.